# How can I create a many to many relationship using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I create a many to many relationship using the models below:

```
class Association(Base):
    a_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('a.id'), index=True)
    b_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('b.some_other_id'))

class A(Base):
     id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)

class B(Base):
     id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
     some_other_id = Column(String(100), index=True, unique=True)
```

Comment: maybe the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting from [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many): You do not need to have the association model at all, if you do not need to have extra attributes for the association:

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('a_id', Integer, ForeignKey('a.id')),
    Column('b_id', Integer, ForeignKey('b.some_id'))
)

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_s = relationship("B",
                    secondary=association_table,
                    backref="a_s")

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    some_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Then `b.a_s` is a collection of `A` and `a.b_s` is a collection of `B`; changes therein will be reflected in the database on `session.flush()`.

If you **do** want to have extra properties for the association between each `A` and `B`, then you can use the [Association object pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object):

```
class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))
    child = relationship("Child")

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `relationship` function of `sqlalchemy.orm` and make sure to declare a primary key in your join table.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, BigInteger, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base=declarative_base()


class Association(Base):
        __tablename__='association'
        a_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('a.id'), index=True, primary_key=True)
        b_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('b.some_other_id'), primary_key=True)

class A(Base):
         __tablename__='a'
         id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
         b_ids = relationship('B', secondary=Association)

class B(Base):
         __tablename__='b'
         id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
         some_other_id = Column(String(100), index=True, unique=True)
         a_ids = relationship('A', secondary=Association)
```